# How to bring this equation to the lowest form until we can't break it down anymore?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

[image]

And I plug in the following value for h:

[image]

How do I go from that to this:

[image]

I tried the following and this is as far as I got but now I'm stuck.

[image]

I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use $\;\sqrt{\dfrac AB}=\dfrac{\sqrt{A}}{\sqrt{B}}$ and $\dfrac A{\,\dfrac BC\,}=\dfrac{AC}B.$

Comment: I get to the next step: M2 * √d/√M2 + D * √M2/√D. What do I do next?

Comment: Well, you could simplify. What's the definition of a square root?

Comment: for M2 * sqrt( d/M2)
that can be simplified to sqrt (M2 *  D)
because M2 = sqrt(M2^2). Thanks I got it.

Comment: That's it. What about the second term?